# Having trouble with a library book class java assignment

Tags: java, if-statement, methods, nested

I have an assignment where I was given a pre-written driver program for a Date class and a LibraryBook class, and I have to write the classes so that they pass a bunch of checks in the driver program. My problem comes with one of the checks where it sees if I will be charged for returning a book on time. Obviously I should be charged $0 but for some reason my program says $15.
Here's the method for calculating the fine:

```
    public double getFineAmount(Date dateReturned){
        double fine;
        Date dueDate = this.getDueDate();
        if(dateReturned.isOnOrBefore(dueDate)){
            fine = 0.00;
        }
        else{
            if(this.isFiction){
                fine = 1.2 * dueDate.getDaysUntil(dateReturned);
                if(fine > 15){
                    fine = 15.00;
                }
            }
            else{
                fine = 1.5 * dueDate.getDaysUntil(dateReturned);
                if(fine > 20){
                    fine = 20.00;
                }
            }
        }
        return fine;
    }
```

When the date the book is borrowed is Feb. 10th, 2012 and the due date is March 2nd, 2012 for some reason the isOnOrBefore method returns false. Here is the isOnOrBefore method:

```
public boolean isOnOrBefore(Date other){
boolean onOrBefore;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(other.toString()).useDelimiter("-");
int otherDay = sc.nextInt();
int otherMonth = sc.nextInt();
int otherYear = sc.nextInt();
if(otherYear >= this.year){
    if(otherMonth >= this.month){
        if(otherDay >= this.day){
            onOrBefore = true;
        }
        else{
            onOrBefore = false;
        }
    }
    else{
        onOrBefore = false;
    }
}
else{
    onOrBefore = false;
}
return onOrBefore;
}
```

I believe the problem is caused by a leap year but I don't see what's causing the error. Here's the code to detect a leap year in case it helps

```
public boolean isLeapYear(){
boolean leapYear;
if(this.year % 100 == 0){
    if(this.year % 400 == 0){
    leapYear = true;
    }
    else{
    leapYear = false;
    }
}
else{
    if(this.year % 4 == 0){
    leapYear = true;
    }
    else{
    leapYear = false;
    }
}
return leapYear;
}
```

I can post more of the code if needed.

Answer (score 1):

How do you debug code? That's the real question here, and that's how it should be answered. Approaches to debugging are varied and should differ based on the use case. In your situation, I'd consider the following:

1. System.out.println (..) statements both before and after the suspect conditionals to determine if the if statements are behaving as planned and whether the values going into them are as expected.
2. Log files that write out specified information at key points in the code to a file so that the entire execution flow of the program can be analyzed. Look at Log4J.
3. Debugger execution in an IDE like Eclipse.

Hint: Are you passing the dates into the method as expected?

Note: You can reduce the length of the code -- i.e. the number of code blocks -- by setting boolean onOrBefore to false and simply testing for the affirmative conditions where it would be set to true.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the call to `isOnOrBefore` closely:

```
// if <Feb. 10 2012>.isOnOrBefore(<Mar. 2 2012>))

public boolean isOnOrBefore(Date other) {
    boolean onOrBefore;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(other.toString()).useDelimiter("-");
    int otherDay = sc.nextInt(); // 2
    int otherMonth = sc.nextInt(); // 3, assuming 1-indexed months
    int otherYear = sc.nextInt(); // 2012
    if(otherYear >= this.year) { // 2012 >= 2012 == true
        if(otherMonth >= this.month) { // 3 >= 2 == true
            if(otherDay >= this.day) { // 2 >= 10 == false
                onOrBefore = true;
            }
            else {
                onOrBefore = false; // onOrBefore == false
            }
        }
        else {
            onOrBefore = false;
        }
    }
    else {
        onOrBefore = false;
    }
    return onOrBefore; // return false
}
```

The problem is that you should only be checking the days if this date and the other date are in the same month. (And similarly, you should only be checking the months if they're in the same year.)

Try this (note that, even if the day/month/year fields are private, you can access them in `other` since you're still in the `Date` class):

```
public boolean isOnOrBefore(Date other) {
    if (other.year > this.year) { // 2012 > 2012 == false
        return true;
    }
    if (other.year < this.year) { // 2012 < 2012 == false
        return false;
    }

    // At this point, we know the two dates are in the same year.

    if (other.month > this.month) { // 3 > 2 == true
        return true; // return true
    }
    if (other.month < this.month) {
        return false;
    }

    // At this point, we know the two dates are in the same month *of the same year*

    return other.day >= this.day;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your leap year algorithm looks backwards.

```
if (year is not divisible by 4) then (it is a common year)    
else if (year is not divisible by 100) then (it is a leap year)    
else if (year is not divisible by 400) then (it is a common year)    
else (it is a leap year)
```

<strike>You may also want to cast to a double in your "if( fine > X)" statements , that way you aren't converting from double to int and risking round off errors.</strike>

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might help you, works 100% to calculate your fine...

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException{

    Scanner date_1 = new Scanner ( System.in);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

  // lend Date- This is not required 
    System.out.println("Enter in the format: YYYY-MM-DD");
    String inputDate = date_1.next();
    Date lendDate = sdf.parse(inputDate);
    System.out.println(lendDate);
 // duedate   
    System.out.println("Enter DueDate in the format:");
    String inputDate1 = date_1.next();
    Date dueDate = sdf.parse(inputDate1);
    System.out.println(dueDate);
 //returnDate    
    System.out.println("Enter return Date");
    String inputDate2 = date_1.next();
    Date returnDate = sdf.parse(inputDate2);
    System.out.println(returnDate);

    long diff = returnDate.getTime() -  dueDate.getTime();

        long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
        long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
        long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
        long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        // Fine amount should be declared or can be added as a user input(optional).    
        long fine = (diffDays)*10 ;
    // if the returnDate has exceeded the duedate                   
if (returnDate.after(dueDate)){
    System.out.print(diffDays + " days, ");
    System.out.print(diffHours + " hours, ");
    System.out.print(diffMinutes + " minutes, ");
    System.out.print(diffSeconds + " seconds." );
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("The Fine is" +fine);   }                    
else{
    System.out.println("Checked out"); }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your answer could be improved a lot if you added some explanation of how your code works.